# Interpreting accuracy in models with caret

Tags: r, r-caret

When I create a model by splitting the data in test/train, I train it with the train part, and then I test the accuracy by making a prediction of test, and comparing it with the real target.

When I create a model with cross-validation, which is the equivalent metric? It should be the mean of all comparations with predictions for each train/test fold. Is this the value in model$results$Accuracy?

My question comes because I get much worse results in cv Accuracy than when I check predictions in my simple train/test partition

I paste code:

```
library(caret)
library(ranger)

set.seed(42)
data(iris)

#Train/test
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train <- iris[trainIndex, ]
test <- iris[-trainIndex, ]

model1 <- ranger(
  Species ~.,
  importance = "impurity",
  num.trees = 200,
  mtry = 2,
  splitrule = "gini",
  min.node.size = 1,
  data = train, 
  seed=42
)

predictions <- predict(model1, data = test)

print(paste("Train/Test Accuracy:", mean(predictions$predictions == test$Species)))

#Cross Validation
control <- trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 3,
  p = 0.8
)

tgrid <- expand.grid(
  .mtry = 2,
  .splitrule = "gini",
  .min.node.size = 1
)


model2 <- train(
  Species ~.,
  data = iris,
  method = "ranger",
  trControl = control,
  tuneGrid = tgrid,
  num.trees=200,
  seed=42
)

print(model2$results$Accuracy)
```

Thanks :)